# Dynamically refresh a div without a straightful DOM manipulation

Tags: node.js, express

I have to update for example a table, a list if some values. I can insert new values and try to reload a entire page to show table or list values again.

If I give a try on Ajax updates I have to manipulate DOM, creating a bunch of new tags, concatenate and inject the new HTML on old one. This not a painful way, you even must re-type the code created before to exhibit new entries.

E.g: this is a fictitious example and illustrates what I mean:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/post/addComment/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'comment=' + comment,
    beforeSend : function() {
        //waiting message
        $('#some_information_div').html('<strong>Updating...</strong>');
    }
}).done(function(data) {
        //new data comes here (by JSON, plain text, whatever...)
        if (data.status == 'OK') {
            //OHHH MAN WE HAVE TO POPULATE MANUALLY IT AGAIN
            var c = '';
            c = '<table>'

            data.content.forEach(function(e) {
                c += '<tr><td>' + e.name + '</td></tr>';
            });

            c += '</table>'

            //update with new values
            $('#some_information_div').html('');
            $('#destination_table').html(c);
        }
});
```

Unfortunately I have to do all the time with my lists and tables and somehow I have to re-type codes and manipulate it all by the javascript. I figured out something might be useful like does [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), maybe it can fit what I want to, I have not tried it.

Some other languages and frameworks like JSF do it easily with "render technique", you directly update content without have to create and manipulate DOM in manually way.

Please, any kind of suggestion, any clue to this approach will be very helpful.

P.S.: The code sample tag doesn't work well here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using `.load()` jquery function. I have illustrated for some page 1.php and some table having id mytable

```
$('table#mytable').load('./1.php #mytable');
```

for constant refreshing --

```
setInterval(function() {
$('tablev#mytable').load('./1.php #mytable');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I was really skeptic about this approach because I though how can it access the the fresh items without implicit server method access. Whatever, it worked out. Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to do this without jquery?